# Dotnet 7 Minimal API swagger browser ui refuse to work

Tags: swagger-ui, asp.net-minimal-apis

Strange issue. My swagger Browser UI (for development testing) is working. I am using port **5060** (in launchsettings.json, profile http), and due to testing requirement, I am changing to **5061, 5062** from time to time.

After many times of changes, swagger browser ui refuses to launch, even if I copy the entire solution to another computer.

I have to use a new port like **5063, 5064** and so on.

And `curl http://localhost:<port A>/swagger/v1/swagger.json` still response even when the browser ui says the page is not available `http://localhost:<port A>/swagger/index.html`.